# How to calculate the mean value of the 3 subsequent points on a loop on an effective way in R

Tags: r, loops, mean

I am trying to calculate the fluxes of phosphate applying the general formula:

F= -krho2 * d(P2-P1)/d(z2-z1) - krho1 * d(P1-P0)/d(z1-z0) written as:

```
Flu_1[i] <- -df44$krho[i+1]*(df4$Phosphate[i+1]-df4$Phosphate[i])/(df44$Depth[i+1]-df44$Depth[i]) - df44$krho[i]*(df44$Phosphate[i]-df4$Phosphate[i-1])/(df44$Depth[i]-df44$Depth[i-1])
```

But I am having some trouble to apply that formula because it gets very lengthy as I need to do the mean of 3 points at each step. I wonder if there is a way to calculate the mean value of three points in a more elegant way. The problem is that the formula gets so lengthy that i tent to do errors with the () brackets.

so I got at the moment a very lengthy formula to calculate Flu_1 given df44

```
Depth <- c(99.92047 ,100.42265 ,100.94351 ,101.49154 ,101.49154, 102.06895, 102.65300, 103.22167, 103.78107, 104.34240,104.90919, 105.48243, 106.06067, 106.64186 ,107.22266, 107.79475, 108.35091, 108.89342,109.42737,109.95948,110.49694 ,111.04430 ,111.59580, 112.14390,112.68424, 113.21562,113.74625, 114.28672 ,114.84307, 115.40328,115.95459, 116.49954, 117.04479, 117.59821,118.16798,118.75777, 119.35323 ,119.93831 ,120.50840, 121.06288,121.60563 ,122.13841, 122.64992, 123.12560 ,123.55157,123.91674 ,124.21265 ,124.43866 ,124.59617 ,124.68674,124.71200, 124.68063, 124.62943 ,124.60175, 124.63884 ,124.77147, 124.99055 ,125.27705, 125.60735,125.93964,126.23798 ,126.50830 ,126.76194 ,126.99021 ,127.17937 ,127.31813 ,127.40495, 127.44802 ,127.48466, 127.55065,127.64658 ,127.76420)

Krho <- c( -5.286844, -5.286844 ,-5.072112 ,-5.072112 ,-5.016449 ,-5.016449, -4.840471,-4.840471, -4.840471, -4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141 ,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141 ,-4.969141 ,-4.969141 ,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141 ,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141 ,-4.969141 ,-4.969141 ,-4.969141 ,-4.969141 ,-4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141 ,-4.969141,-4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141, -4.969141 ,-4.969141 ,-4.969141, -4.969141,-4.969141,-4.969141,-4.969141,-4.969141 ,-4.969141)

Phosphate <- c(1.2775859, 1.2494627 ,1.2162273 ,1.1791951 ,1.1791951, 1.1398022 ,1.0999701, 1.0615126,1.0253303,0.9920223,0.9618954,0.9352211,0.9124229,0.8939618,0.8801429,0.8706457,0.8648398,0.8614785,0.8592499,0.8571969,0.8544512,0.8503440,0.8450059,0.8389027,0.8330438,0.8283908,
0.8251727, 0.8234350, 0.8230596, 0.8232740,0.8232948, 0.8229505, 0.8221870, 0.8208087, 0.8185845,0.8152875,0.8107066,0.8047596,0.7978633,0.7905728,0.7834964,0.7772102,0.7721074,0.768, 0.7667334, 0.7665123, 0.7674906, 0.7689529, 0.7702238 ,0.7711219,
0.7715893, 0.7716646 ,0.7717726, 0.7723444 ,0.7734504, 0.7749810, 0.7764664,0.7773463,0.7771001, 0.7753641,0.7719523, 0.7672308, 0.7616953, 0.7558070, 0.7500182, 0.7447203, 0.7400592, 0.7361163,0.7329601, 0.7306044,0.7288592, 0.7274832)

df44  <- data.frame(Depth,Krho,Phosphate)


du44<- as.data.frame(matrix( 0, nrow(df44), ncol= 2))
names(du44) <- c("Depth","Flux_PO4")
Flu_1 <- 0)
du44[1,1]<- df44$Depth[1]
du44[1,2]<- Flu_1



for(i in 2:nrow(df44)) {
  Flu_1[i] <- -df44$krho[i+2]*(mean(df44$Phosphate[i+2]+df44$Phosphate[i+3]+df44$Phosphate[i+4])-mean(df44$Phosphate[i+1]+df44$Phosphate[i+2]+df44$Phosphate[i+3]))/
(mean(df44$Depth[i+2]+df44$Depth[i+3]+df44$Depth[i+4])-mean(df44$Depth[i+1]+df44$Depth[i+2]+df44$Depth[i+3]))-(df44$krho[i+1]*(mean(df44$Phosphate[i]+df44$Phosphate[i+1]+df44$Phosphate[i+2])- mean(df44$Phosphate[i-1]+df44$Phosphate[i]+df44$Phosphate[i+1]))/(mean(df44$Depth[i+1]+df44$Depth[i+2]+df44$Depth[i+3])-mean(df44$Depth[i-1]+df44$Depth[i]+df44$Depth[i+1])))
  du44[i,1]<- df44$Depth[i]
  du44[i,2]<- Flu_1[i]
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead` and `lag` to get next and previous value respectively to perform the calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
df44 %>%
  mutate(Flu_1 = -lead(Krho)*(lead(Phosphate)-Phosphate)/(lead(Depth)-Depth) - 
           Krho*(Phosphate-lag(Phosphate))/(Depth-lag(Depth))) -> df44

df44
```